# Discord.Net getting bot online doesn't work

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

trying to work with Discord.NET 1.0 and following foxbot guide

[fotbox guide](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/intro.html)

I used this code:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;


namespace MyBot
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        => new Program().StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        private DiscordSocketClient _client;

        public async Task StartAsync()
        {
            _client = new DiscordSocketClient();
            await _client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "Mzmkl......");
            await _client.StartAsync();
            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }
   }
}
```

And trying to compile does not getting my bot online. I followed the steps, my bot is included. [Bot included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P12qH.png)

Comment: Make sure your token is correct. I know you put "......" so no one can steal it but make sure it is correct. Also, take away "Task.Delay(-1);" and see what that does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was the System.PlatformNotSupportedException error. I work with Win7.
Solution was installing WS4NET and adding this:

```
_client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig { 
    WebSocketProvider = Discord.Net.Providers.WS4Net.WS4NetProvider.Instance
 });
```